# NO mail send on using django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler

Tags: python, django, email, logging

I am tryin to use django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler for sending error messages to admin on 500 but cannot figure out the error followed the django docs returned status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR from get call to raise error

here is the code:

```
ADMINS =(('admin','xyz@gmail.com'),)
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'xyz@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xyz@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*****'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS = True

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'oodles/debug.log',
        },

    },

    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins', 'file', ],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your logger is looking for `DEBUG` level. `5xx` response errors fall under `ERROR` level.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/#django-request

Comment: but When a message is given to the logger, the log level of the message is compared to the log level of the logger. If the log level of the message meets or exceeds the log level of the logger itself, the message will undergo further processing. 
in this case error message is exceeding the debug level